# Why is number of capture groups different here?

Tags: ruby, regex, capture-group

I had this small regex, let's call it **Regex-small**:

```
(?:\.$|\:$|\: ([^\:]*?)$|\. (#{Rx_abbr_lit}(?:, #{Rx_abbr_lit})?)\.?$|$)
```

I use that regex inside a larger, compound regex, which I will call `Regex-BIG`. The `Regex-BIG` finds two capture groups without trouble and then tries matching `Regex-small`. `Regex-small` is supposed to match ending of string. If it has anything after the colon, or contains 1 or 2 abbreviations (`Rx_abbr_lit` is just a long alternative without capturing groups), it captures it. Hence, `Regex-BIG` should have 3 capture groups, the final one returning a string or a nil.

However, when I tried adding another condition to `Regex-small`, it ended up capturing what I wanted, but as capture group 4, not 3 (3 is always empty):

```
(?:\.$|\:$|((?:#{Rx_abbr_combo_All})\: [^\:]*?)$|\: ([^\:]*?)$|\. (#{Rx_abbr_lit}(?:, #{Rx_abbr_lit})?)\.?$|$)
```

`Rx_abbr_combo_All` is just another alternative of abbreviations, and successfully captures things like that:

> abbr.: There is some text here.

Why does this addition of one alternative change behavior of my `Regex-BIG`? The number of capture groups is always 0 or 1 inside each alternative.

These are the examples I have been working on:

- forma ż. od Facet; dziewczyna lekka: To ci, panie, szyk F.! Gom. Co to za F.?
  rz. od Fakcyjny; działanie w interesie fakcji: Bał ś., żeby go nie posądzono o F. Tarn.
- przym. od Fałda; **gieol.: Góry, doliny fałdowe = powstałe wskutek kurczenia ś. skorupy ziemskiej.**
- przym. od Fankiel; **apt.: Ulepek F. (syrupus foeniculi) = ulepek z kopru włoskiego.**
- przym. od Fartuszek; przen. kobiecy, babski: Fartuszkową zyskawszy protekcję, pobrali buławy, klucze i pieczęcie. Kaczk. Fartuszkowe fawory. Kaczk.
- przym. od Feler; mający felery; wybrakowany, wysortowany: Towar F. (= brak).
- przym. od Fernambuk; **bot.: Drzewo fernambukowe p. Fernambuk.**
- przym. od Fetyszyzm; Fetyszerski bałwochwalczy.
- przym. od Fijolet; Fjoletowy fijołkowy: Kwarc F. = ametyst. Kolor F. Pomalować na fijoletowo (= na kolor F.).
- przym. od Fracht; ×Fraktowy, ×Frochtowy transportowy, przewozowy, ładowny, ciężki: F. wóz a. buda frachtowa. Wagon, statek. F. Poczta frachtowa. List F. p. Fracht. Makler P. (= dostarczający furmanom i szyprom ładunku za pewnym wynagrodzeniem).
- przym. od Fryjer; †Fryjowny rozwiązły, lubieżny, wszeteczny, rozpustny.
- przym. od Futro; podbity futrem: Kołnierz F. Rękawice futrzane.

Comment: Just make  sure the groups inside `Rx_abbr_combo_All` and `Rx_abbr_lit` are non-capturing. You will have the order of the groups unaffected then.

Comment: That was my first thought. Oddly enough, there are no groups **whatsoever** in those two